# Can i integrate BI Reports within an app?

Tags: app, integration, bi

Sorry for the vague question, but can I add BI-functionalities to a Sharepoint app?  Currently I am working on an app which will have a lot of SharePoint hosted functionalities (lists, workflows, document libraries etc). The app will be installed at customer's SharePoint sites where a group of users will start to use the app and fill the app with data etc. Once installed I cannot get to the app anymore so my job is done.

However, I wonder if I could add for example a page/dashboard that displays KPI's/statistics calculated from the activities in the app. I probably would need access to the app's database for that. I read everywhere that the database of the app is not accessible, does this imply that what I want is mission impossible?

Anything that points me in a direction will be highly appreciated!